# UITextField data isn't uploading to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uitextfield

I'm wanting this activity of my app to get what is entered into the UItextfield and save it to Firebase.

Xcode is showing no errors when I run my app but the text isn't uploading to firebase

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Admin_events: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var event_text: UITextField!

var ref : DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    ref=Database.database().reference()
}
@IBAction func sendtofirebase(_ sender: Any) {
    let event = event_text.text
ref?.child("Events").setValue(event)
    NSLog("Uploading...")
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didReceiveMemoryWarning` is only called when the system is running low on memory. Under most common circumstances, this won't even be called at all, meaning your `ref` property will remain nil.

Try setting the property somewhere else. `viewDidLoad` is called very early on (and only once) during the view controller's lifecycle, so it's a good place to do this type of setup.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Admin_events: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var event_text: UITextField!

    var ref : DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // One-time setup is commonly done here.
        // This is a good time to create your database reference.

        ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

    @IBAction func sendtofirebase(_ sender: Any) {
        let event = event_text.text
        ref?.child("Events").setValue(event)
        NSLog("Uploading...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked and I can't believe I missed that!